# How to check naming Convention for static global variables in C using clang-tidy?

Tags: c, clang-tidy

I'm trying to set up clang-tidy to check the right naming conventions for global variables. I'd like it to be able to distinguish between global static and global non-static variables.

```c
int globalNonStatic = 1; /* Should be camelBack */
static int GlobalStatic = 0; /* Should be CamelCase */
```

However, I can't find find which readability-identifier-naming option to use to distinguish between the 2

I've tried to do something like:

```yaml
Checks: '-*,readability-identifier-naming'
CheckOptions:
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.GlobalVariableCase,  value: camelBack }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.VariableCase,        value: CamelCase }
```

A similar approach (GlobalFunctionCase/FunctionCase) seemed to work for distinguishing between static and non-static functions. I got the following warning when running:

```
warning: invalid case style for global variable 'GlobalStatic' [readability-identifier-naming]
static int GlobalStatic = 0; /* Should be CamelCase */
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
           globalStatic
```

I've also tried with the following options, but no luck:

- StaticVariableCase
- LocalVariableCase

Am I missing a specific (undocumented) option that can be used to achieve different style checks for static/non-static global variables?

Edit: Also found an issue reported on the subject in the LLVM issue tracker, but no replies yet (since 2019): https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42634

Comment: "I'd like it to be able to distinguish between global static and global non-static variables."  Please reconsider. Inventing strange, private coding styles not used by anybody else in the whole world isn't a great idea.